# Finding a backend for an agularjs app for gae

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, backend

I am building an angular app and the next step is to put it on GAE and I was wondering what backend should I use. I have my html pages ready I just need now to set up a backend so I can store and retrieve data for my little project. An information on this would be great. I don't think I would need to use jinja for this.

Comment: What do you men by "what backend"? Does GAE have many backend options ?

Comment: Well it gives me php, go, python, and java Google App Engine: Platform as a Service. The problem I am having is that i have angular doing my templates. All I want is to be able to store data on GAE and I am trying to figure that out. Their example use jinja2 but I don't think I need to use that since I am using angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you say, Angular will be used for UI. For the backend, GAE being PaaS, it gives you number of services. One of the services is persistence. It's done using either the [Data Store Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) (NoSQL) or [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/). You can also make REST API around your persistence and business logic in the backend using [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) that you can [use in JavaScript client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js).

To develop the backend and make use of these services you have many options: PHP, Python, Java, Go, ... . You can pick the one you like and more familiar with.

If you decide to use Java, you may want to take a look at Objectify. It makes your persistence code simpler and clearer than using the Data Store API directly. Also [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) will make it much easier for you.

Note that although I used links here for services in Java, there are similar pages for python and other languages too. So you can use the same services in your favorite language.